# Crystal Reports will insert certain images but not others

Tags: visual-studio-2010, image, crystal-reports

Are there specific requirements for images that are to be inserted into CR?

I’m trying to insert an image into Crystal reports, but nothing happens after I select my file.  I have a different image that I’ve used for testing that inserts with no problems so I’m assuming that it has something to do with the JPG file settings when saving the image. Note that this is just a static logo for a page header – nothing is being dynamically loaded.

I know that GIFs cannot be used, so I’ve tried JPG and PNG to no avail.  I’ve even saved my “working” image again through Photoshop and it will insert.  I’ve then used those settings to save the non-working image, but that image wont insert. I’ve used Crystal Reports a lot in the past and this is the first time I’ve come across this issue and my searches lead me to a variety of resources for dynamic image inclusion, but nothing to for this hopefully simple issue.

I’m using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010.

[Link to images used in testing](http://sandbox.gndev.com/crimages.zip)

Comment: Why don't you post both the images (working and not working)?

Comment: Could it bi a size (in pixel) limit? Have you tried setting it very small (ie 5%)?

Comment: @EmanueleGreco - I added a link to the a small zip file containing the two images.  Interestingly, the large of the two images is the one that works, and the smaller does not.

Comment: I have a working solution, but can't answer my own question for another hour.  Stay tuned and I'll post it when I'm able.  Thanks to everyone who read this and helped out.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After messing with this problem all day, I found out it’s a bug in the Crystal Reports IDE.

Here’s how to duplicate the issue:

1. Right click on your report and select Insert >> Picture
2. Double-click on the image that you wish to insert.

Depending on your image and how the image was saved in Photoshop, it may or may not insert into the report.  I’ve had mixed results and apparently some images work and some do not.  I haven’t quite figured out the pattern yet, but I believe it has to do with the color profiles of the image.  I probably won’t waste any more time investigating it, because the following resolution has worked for me every time and I can import every image that I’ve created in Photoshop regardless of how the image was saved and the settings used to save the images.  (Assuming that they’re all JPGs, of course.)

Resolution:

1. Right click on your report and select Insert >> Picture
2. SINGLE-click on the image that you wish to insert to select it.
3. Click “Open”

The image should insert into the report properly.

It’s a subtle difference, but I hope this saves someone else a few hours of debugging.

Dave

Comment: I've had better luck using bmp rather than jpg or png.

Answer (score 0):

Worked AOK for me. Check if you have all the latest patches. I've attached a screenshot in Crystal 2011 and saved the .rpt for you to try and open in Visual Studio 2010: http://speedy.sh/RGgfg/crimages.zip

[image]

Comment: Thanks for testing this for me and confirming that it did work.  I had trouble with the small blue image, but it turned out that it was an issue with the tool and not an issue with the image.  I was trying to use CR for Visual Studio 2010 and not the stand-alone SAP editor so that might make a difference and hopefully the bug I identified above doesn't exist in the stand alone tool!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because the format is not supported, I had exactly the same problem but when I saved the file as JPG it started working perfectly!.

Answer (score 0):

i think crytal report does not accept some image formats but what i did when i encountered the problem was to 
1. open the image with coreldraw
2. copy the image content of the image and paste it in the crystal report instead of using the insert tool on crystal report and it worked

hope this will also be helpul.