# Using image resizer in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, imageresizer

Anyone know how or why the `ImageResizer` will not work in crystal reports?

If you paste the URL 
`xxxx.jpg.ashx?width=50` into a browser, works great.

The exact same path shows nothing when used as a image location in crystal reports (Remove the `.ashx?width=50` and it immediately works again).  So it's as if the image resizer is unable to execute when called from the crystal reports viewer? (I do not understand why since we have verified that any user, even without being authenticated, can reach the path through a browser)

Crystal Reports 2008, Version 12.2.0.290

In terms of diagnosing the issue, in short involving the image resizer process (by including the .ashx?width=50 on the end of the URL) is the only thing that prevents the image from showing. And this only occurs in crystal. Browsers handle the URL just fine.

UPDATE : Testing without the .ashx also proved to not work. The ?width=50 after .jpg is enough for crystal to just display a blank. (No errors, just no image)

UPDATE : Testing using &format=png or &format=jpg also did not work (Blank in crystal, works perfect in browser)

FINAL UPDATE : We ended up placing the image re-sizer software on a stand alone (what used to be a file manager box) away from our web.config, permissions, and web server and then crystal started rendering the images just fine. So we never really figured out WHY crystal could not render the images when the re-sizer software was loaded on our IIS web server\intranet.....(possibly due to integrated windows authentication turned on even though we granted access to the folder the images were in) ......but it did start working just fine when we bypassed all of that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying an alternate URL syntax to determine if Crystal Reports is simply allergic to query strings.

1. Try the [FolderResizeSyntax plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/folderresizesyntax) "folder/resize(50,50)/image.jpg
2. Try the [CloudFront plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/cloudfront): "folder/image.jpg;width=50"

Comment: We have had other querystring references work in crystal before. In fact a image re-sizing program that worked very similar, (but was bundled with an old product management software) had a URL with a size and width query string that would return a .jpg file to the browser\report

Comment: For the record we tried the resize(50,50) URL and it still does not work in crystal.

Comment: Complete. We have been able to get both the following URLs to work in a browser. http://intranet/images/syracuse.jpg.ashx?width=50 as well as http://intranetdev/images/syracuse.jpg?width=50 However the same paths will appear blank in crystal.......BUT...when the URL is this http://intranet/images/syracuse.jpg crystal displays the image just fine

Comment: Try adding &format=png - perhaps it's [related to this Crystal Reports bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10193508/crystal-reports-will-insert-certain-images-but-not-others)

Comment: No go. Tried URL http://intranet/images/syracuse.jpg.ashx?width=50&format=png and its blank....however URL http://intranet/images/syracuse.jpg still works fine

Comment: btw I can still take the exact same URL that does not display the image in crystal and copy it to a browser and it works perfectly

Comment: Ok, so we've exhausted the shotgun programming options. We need to set up Fiddler to see what exactly Crystal Reports is calling and what it gets back.

Answer (score 0):

FINAL UPDATE : We ended up placing the image re-sizer software on a stand alone (what used to be a file manager box) away from our web.config, permissions, and web server and then crystal started rendering the images just fine. So we never really figured out WHY crystal could not render the images when the re-sizer software was loaded on our IIS web server\intranet.....(possibly due to integrated windows authentication turned on even though we granted access to the folder the images were in) ......but it did start working just fine when we bypassed all of that stuff.